# Prevent XSS in chat

Tags: c#, html, encoding

If I remove "<" and ">" characters in the chat is the string then secure enough to be embedded in an html page? How can I sanitize and escape the HTML properly in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Don't guess, use a function made for the job:

[HTTPUtility.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx)

Instead of removing "unsafe" strings, encode any character that might be parsed as HTML into an HTML Entity.

If this isn't a web-app, the similar functions can be found in `WebUtility`.